# ЧПУ .htaccess (PHP)

Tags: php, .htaccess, чпу, hosting

Ребят, привет всем. Подскажите как убрать отображение .php в адресной строке через .htaccess. К примеру есть страница test.ru/post.php?title=Новость, как сделать нормальный её вид? Даже если просто test.ru/post.php, но при этом чтобы это все отображалось нормально. Подскажите кто сталкивался. Буду очень благодарен за статейку или совет!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [L,QSA]
```

Можно попробовать так. Как альтернативный вариант:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Благодарен, за подсказку. Решение действительно работает, хочу ещё посмотреть на ответы.

Comment: @w3cwhy http://astra.red/rukovodstvo-po-htaccess-tryuki-i-priemyi/#:~:text=%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20.,%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0.

Comment: я блин никогда не пойму, зачем вот это вот ?p=$1 всегда пихается